# How to check whether data of a row is in list, inside of np.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, np

```
developed_countries = ["NOR","AUS","CHE","DEU","DNK","SGP","NLD","IRL","ISL","CAN","USA","NZL","SWE","LIE","GBR"]

recent_indicators['Developed'] = np.where(recent_indicators['CountryCode'] in developed_countries, 1, 0)
```

> "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

**recent_indicators** is pandas DataFrame. What can be the alternative to check if the 'CountryCode' is mentioned in developed_countries?

Comment: What is the desired output? Please show an example of your df input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.isin()` directly in pandas filtering -

```
recent_indicators_filtered = recent_indicators[recent_indicators['CountryCode'].isin(developed_countries)]
```

Also, you can come up with a boolean column that says `True` if developed -

```
recent_indicators['Developed'] = recent_indicators['CountryCode'].isin(developed_countries)
```